# monitoring applications file access in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, monitoring, filesystemwatcher

I need to monitor applications File Access in win 7 operating system. I want to monitor which software read, write or create file in which place. I think, this work is imposible with File System Watcher and auditing. how can I do this work with C#? Are there any appropriate APIs?

Comment: All files in the system, or a limited subset?

Comment: all files.. It's an application for increasing security of system.

Comment: Windows would do that for you - consider filesystem-level auditing.

Comment: But it's impossible to recognize which program read or write a file. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a filesystem filter driver for fine-grain monitoring and tracking what applications access files. Developing a kernel-mode driver requires C programming and special knowledge. You can write a driver yourself ([read MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx)) or use our [CallbackFilter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/) product (it provides a pre-created driver and .NET API for integration with your software).